# Prove Cauchy-Green integral formula for a null-homotopic curve

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

In complex analysis, I am trying to prove the following theorem:

Theorem：Suppose $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a region (i.e. $\Omega$ is a connected open set), $\gamma $ is a null-homotopic curve on $\Omega $,  $f$ is an analytic function on $\Omega $ , then for any $z \in \Omega \backslash {\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} \gamma $ , we have

$$ Ind_\gamma \left( z \right) f\left( z \right) = \frac {1} {2\pi \rm{i}} \int_\gamma \frac {f\left(\xi \right)} {\xi - z} d\xi $$

where $Ind_\gamma \left( z \right) \equiv \frac{1}{2\pi \rm{i}}\int_\gamma  \frac{1}{{\xi  - z}}d\xi  $ is winding number.

According to my teacher, we can prove the theorem in the following way: We only need to show $\frac{1}{2\pi \rm{i}}\int_\gamma  {\frac{f\left( \xi  \right) - f\left( z \right)}{\xi  - z}d\xi }  = 0$. Since $\gamma $ is null-homotopic, we can deform $\gamma $ in $\Omega \backslash \{ z \} $ to be a small circle $\sigma $ around $z$. Then by Cauchy-Goursat theorem for homotopic curves, we have
$$\int_\gamma  {\frac{{f\left( \xi  \right) - f\left( z \right)}}{{\xi  - z}}d\xi }  = \int_\sigma  {\frac{{f\left( \xi  \right) - f\left( z \right)}}{{\xi  - z}}d\xi } $$
It is easy to see that the latter can be arbitrarily small, thus the assertion holds.

**My question is: Why can we deform $\gamma $ in $\Omega \backslash \{ z \} $ to be a small circle $\sigma $ around $z$?**

**It seems that γ may not be null-homotopic in $\Omega \backslash \{ z \} $; instead, perhaps we can split the integral along γ into the sum of integrals along some closed curves, such that each of these curves contracts to a very small circle.**

**How to prove it rigorously?**
[image]

However, I found another method to prove this theorem:

In Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis", he proves the Cauchy-Goursat theorem for a closed triangle, which allows a function to be non-analytic at one point on the triangle.

Define $\Phi \left( \xi  \right) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{{f\left( \xi  \right) - f\left( z \right)}}{{\xi  - z}}}&{\xi  \ne z}\\
{f'\left( z \right)}&{\xi  = z}
\end{array}} \right.$. Since the integral along $\gamma $ can be approximated by the integral along piecewise linear curves, we can assume that $\gamma $ is already piecewise linear. Then, suppose we have a homotopy $F:{I^2} \to \Omega $ such that $F:\gamma  \simeq {i_{{z_0}}}$. Utilizing an open ball cover of ${I^2}$ and the Lebesgue number lemma, ${I^2}$ can be partitioned into sufficiently small triangles $\{ \Delta _i\}\}_{i = 1}^n$ and $F$ can be adjusted to be linear on each triangle.
[image]
Now $F$ maps each triangle $\Delta _i$ to triangle $F\left( {{\Delta _i}} \right)$ in $\Omega$. Applying the Cauchy-Goursat theorem on the image of each triangle, we have
$$\int_\gamma  {\Phi \left( \xi \right)d\xi }  = \int_{F\left( {\partial {I^2}} \right)} {\Phi \left( \xi \right)d\xi }  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\int_{F\left( {\partial {\Delta _i}} \right)} {\Phi \left( \xi \right)dz} }  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\int_{\partial F\left( {{\Delta _i}} \right)} {\Phi \left( \xi \right)dz} }  = 0$$

Comment: By the Jordan curve theorem this will only be the case if $z$ lies in the bounded part of $\mathbb{C}\backslash \text{im}(\gamma)$. In this case, the bounded part minus the point $z$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. Otherwise you can contract $\gamma$ in $\Omega\backslash \{z\}$, hence the weighting by winding number.

Comment: @Julius J. The issue here is that $\gamma $ is not necessarily a Jordan curve, it is simply a closed curve of finite length.

Comment: Since you know $\gamma$ is homotopic to a point curve in $\Omega$, why not just write $\int_\gamma  {\frac{{f\left( \xi  \right) - f\left( z \right)}}{{\xi  - z}}d\xi }=\int_\gamma{\Phi \left( \xi  \right) d\xi }  $  and apply Cauchy-Goursat to the right hand side?

Comment: @user8675309 When trying to use the Cauchy-Goursat theorem in this manner, we hope that $\Phi$ is analytic on $\Omega$. Obviously, $\Phi$ is analytic on $\Omega \backslash \{ z \} $. However, how do we prove that Φ is analytic at $z$?

Comment: The way I learned it was via direct manipulation of power series.  Others may look at it in terms of Riemann's theorem on removable singularities.  It is hard to know what it is you know without you stating your background knowledge (or what text you're using, if it is sufficiently well known).

Comment: @user8675309 Using power series seems reasonable, so this is another method of proof. In the lecture notes I am using, we first prove the Cauchy-Goursat theorem, then establish the Cauchy integral formula, and subsequently develop the theory of power series. Therefore, initially, I did not intend to prove it using power series. Indeed,  using power series for the proof does not involve circular reasoning. The establishment of the theory of power series only requires the Cauchy integral formula for a circle, rather than the yet-to-be-proven homotopy version.

Comment: @user8675309 However, this does not address the algebraic topology question I raised in the main text.